# Hyper-V Guest OS activating question

Tags: hyper-v, activation

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 DC and inside this I have 10 Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition SP2. If I understand correctly, I can run as many OS as possible, but how do I activate these OSEs?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I can run as many OS as possible

Yes, you can. Whether it is legal is another question (as in: standard edition does not allow 10 vms without additional licenses).

> but how do I activate these OSEs?

Normally. WAK or KMS. Like any windows instance.

Comment: what do you mean by WAK? is it not MAK? sorry I don't quite understand. Could give me simple explanation on how to use it?

Comment: both Datacentre and Itanium editions lets you have unlimited VMs (http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-specs.aspx) so it is legal. But you're right, there's no other way of activating over and above the usual routes.

Comment: You may realize he said standard edition - not datacenter. and sorry, WAK should be MAK.

Comment: oh that's funny, we both read "DC" differently, I guess you read that as domain controller, whereas I thought he meant "Data Center", as in the edition of windows - I wonder which he really has, of course I assumed this as for the enterprise version you have to run standard edition inside the VMs, don't think that's the case with data center edition. Hmmm... wonder if he could clarify.

Comment: Yeah, possible. if it is a DC as in DataCenter edition then the licensing for unlimited VM's is included ;) I just realize that this is a valid reading, too. The main issue, though - it sucks dealing with VMs and MAK. A KMS is a LOOOOOT better to deal with them.